# laravel 5.4 mysql database error on host server

Tags: php, laravel

I  have 4 projects in laravel 4 and 1 in laravel 5.4 so I uploaded all of them in Host server the 4 (laravel 4) are working but the (laravel 5.4)project dose not works an have error like this.[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVkAa.png)

this is my config.php and .env [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8db17.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the [How do I ask a good questions guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more information

Answer (score 1):

You can try thi way

clean cache  by run these command

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`.

And then restart your server

Comment: I Did php artisan config:clear But Still have the error

Comment: Alternatively, these both commands can be written as a single command as `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @kajab, try `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: One thing you don't need to write hard code in config/app.php file  just  give your credential in .env file   then restart your server

Answer (score 0):

your DB_PORT is wrong (as `localhost`) it should be

```
DB_PORT=3306
```

**another tip**

either create a mysql user `reshad_rphs` or change your `.env` file `DB_USERNAME` to existing user like `root`.

> Its always recommended to use a separate user for apps other than root
>   user.

to test whether everything else works just use root and see.

```
DB_USERNAME=root
```